# "media only screen" not support Safari and IOS

Tags: html, css

Try to apply media only screen for website

- Android :working fine.
- IOS : not working on Safari (desktop, mobile) , Google Chrome (on
  iOS)

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
       .icons-side {
       visibility: hidden;
       }  
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    
    // Display icon 
    }
```

Comment: It's probably doing exactly what you asked. Your queries are more than likely not specific enough, you can set a query based on `width`, `pixel-ratio`, `orientation`, etc. I would recommend reading this guide for media queries for a variety of difference devices, pixel-ratios, orientations, scales: [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: For example, a `Portrait` `Iphone` media query may be: `/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}
`

Answer (score -1):

It is slightly unclear what your problem is here - I'm answering assuming you're trying to hide or display an image based on screen width.

I'd use the display: none; css property to hide the icon versus the visibility. I couldn't use it in the @media query when I tried. Here's the code I did to show resizing and hiding an image - and on JS fiddle. [Resizing and Hiding Image Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/79nvzo08/8/)

```html
<html>
  <style>
      #icon_div { background-color: green;}
      #icon { width: 100px; }

      @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        #icon_div { background-color: red; }
        #icon {display: none;}
      }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 id="icon_div"></h1>
      <img id="icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Godot_icon.svg" >   
    </div>
  </body>
  
  <! –– Script that displays page width and height, for reference ––>
  <script>
    window.onresize = displayWindowSize;
    window.onload = displayWindowSize;

    function displayWindowSize() {
        myWidth = window.innerWidth;
        myHeight = window.innerHeight;
        // your size calculation code here
        document.getElementById("icon_div").innerHTML = "Page width:"+myWidth + " <br>Page Height:" + myHeight;
    };
  </script>
</html>
```